# RPlidar could not be launched

Tags: 16.04, serial-port

I am now doing a project using rplidar in ubuntu 16.04. However I facing some problem of launching the rplidar. I have checked that my `userid` is inside the `dialout` 
group. The below code is what I receive after launching the `roslaunch rplidar_python rplidar.launch`. The rosdistro I am using is kinetic and the rosversion is 1.12.14.

```
process[rplidar-1]: started with pid [10922]
[INFO] [1558528578.411324]: initialization system
[WARN] [1558528578.449588]: find rplidar connect on port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[WARN] [1558528578.451918]: connect port: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[INFO] [1558528578.452421]: sending commands
[INFO] [1558528578.453045]: evaluating header
[INFO] [1558528578.464362]: health status: status_ok
[INFO] [1558528578.465156]: sending commands
[INFO] [1558528578.465766]: evaluating header
```

Can anyone help and solve this problem?

Comment: You haven't told us which release of Ubuntu you are using on your pi, however https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ may have more familiar users with your intended package